# Gradle: Unable to store task input properties. Property 'myInput' with value '[null]' cannot be serialized

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How can you make a Gradle `@Input` work for `List<CustomClass>`? I've tried adding the `toString()` method, this helps but it still fails in weird ways. What's the correct way to make it serializable? This is version 2.4 of Gradle.

Failure: `List<CustomClass>`

```java
@Input
List<CustomClass> getMyInput() {
    List<CustomClass> simpleList = new ArrayList<>()
    simpleList.add(new CustomClass())
    return simpleList
}

static class CustomClass {
    String str
}
```

This fails with the message:

```
"Unable to store task input properties. Property 'myInput' with value '[null]' cannot be serialized."
```

Success: `List<String>`

```java
@Input
List<String> getMyInput() {
    List<String> simpleList = new ArrayList<>()
    simpleList.add(new String('ignore'))
    return simpleList
}
```

Gradle source code reference of where the exception is created:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/changedetection/state/InputPropertiesSerializer.java#L42

Comment: Added note on it being Gradle 2.4. I basically was missing the correct implementation of Serializable. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The class needs to implement the 'Serializable' interface. This is to allow Gradle to fully serialize the object so the binary format can be compared between builds to see if anything has changed. Once CustomClass is serializable, then `List<CustomClass>` will also be serializable as long as it's using standard implementations such as `ArrayList`.

Here's an example:

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode
static class CustomClass implements Serializable {
    // Increment this when the serialization output changes
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String projectName

    @SuppressWarnings('unused')
    private static void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    // Gradle only needs to serialize objects, so this isn't strictly needed
    @SuppressWarnings('unused')
    private static void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
    }
}
```